# Do I have to deploy my site to IIS in order to create user directories?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am getting a *'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'* error when I run my web application and try to upload a file as a logged in app user .

I have a controller that attempts to create the directory if one doesn't exist for the logged in users upload.

**My question is, do I have to deploy my project to IIS in order to programmatically create directories?**

I don't mean IIS Express.

If not, please elaborate on the best way to allow access.

*edited for clarification

Comment: you need to use the user account for the app pool that has permissions to create/access a folder/file. by default in IIS7+ it uses the ApplicationPoolIdentity so this would be why you are getting the error. It has the least amount of permissions.

Comment: so, to clarify, your saying that I do not need to host my site in IIS? I just need to add the user account to the app pool or use the account from the app pool?

Comment: What do you mean, a logged in user directory?

Comment: I've edited my post, hopefully it makes my problem more clear

Comment: it depends. is this a website? if so then of course you need IIS but I am also saying that you need to have a user account in the app pool for your website which has permissions to create the directories on disk. The ApplicationPoolIdentity does NOT have this permission for obvious reasons.

Comment: @ahmed I'm not talking about Visual Studio's IIS Express, I'm wondering if I need to install my site to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: I understand what your saying now, I've been working on it since I posted my question.

Comment: right, and I am referring to the full blown IIS. you need to read up on how IIS works and what App Pools are. :)